# Change css class if input has a value

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I change the CSS class of an input field, if that input field has a value

**Example:**

```
<input name='referrer' type='text' class='input-xlarge placeholder' placeholder='Referrer' value='{$ref}'  style='width:346px;'>
```

Currently, I am doing like this:

```
if ($('#reffield').val() != ''){ $('#reffield').addClass('classname'); }
```

But that doesn't have any effect, nor does it generate any error.

Comment: Do you want to change only '#reffield' (a single element) or several input elements?  While the process would be essentially the same, just want to clarify the example.  If there is no element with id = 'reffield' then it would not work anyway.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "css class". You are dealing with HTML classes.

Comment: You don't have the id in the HTML

Comment: When are people going to understand the difference between ids and names? :/

Comment: @Jonast92 When they make mistakes like this one and learn from them. I'm sure you weren't born an HTML master, were you?

Comment: @Uqi No but I sure do bother to use Google. Mistakes don't bother me but it bothers me when people can't even search a basic <material> <example>.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify the id attribute inside the tag, like this:
    `<input id="reffield" name='referrer' type='text' class='input-xlarge placeholder' placeholder='Referrer' value='{$ref}'  style='width:346px;'>`

Your jQuery selector can't find the element with the id "reffield" based on your HTML.

Answer (score 1):

`#reffield` is [an **id selector**.](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#id-selectors) It matches elements based on the value of their `id` attribute. Your input doesn't have an `id` attribute, you should set one:

```
<input id='referrer' name='referrer' type='text'
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no ID tag found  and

You need to write the script in keydown Function or some condition.

```
$('input').keydown(function(e){

        $("#reffield").css( { backgroundColor:"blue" } );

});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/sureshbm13/wVpcS/2/)

Answer (score 0):

This code change every input class name with value != ""

```
$('input[value!=""]').each(function() {
    this.className = "className";
});
```

if you want change one specific input with a given id

```
<input id="reffield" value="..:" ../>
```

then

```
$('#reffield[value!=""]')[0].className = "className";
```

if you want change a specific input based on name

```
 // if ($('input[name="reffield"][value!=""]')[0])
       $('input[name="reffield"][value!=""]')[0].className = "classname"
```

You can read the [documentation of selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Note: you say "change class" and not "add class". In second case you should use `.addClass` method instead of `.className` property